# Реализация функции деления. С/С++.

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Подскажите алгоритм функции деления на С++ или С.

Answer (score 3):

Ну ... задача необычная, никогда не решал. Сейчас подумал, могу подать идею: возможно, она плохо реализуется. Как учили делить в школе: деление столбиком. Но получается, можно сделать только для целочисленного деления.

В цикле:

- выберите первую цифру;
- если меньше делимого, берете вторую и т.е. пока не будет число больше того, на которое надо делить;
- тут надо подцикл:

  - надо умножать числа от 1 до 9 на делимое до тех пор, пока не получите число > делимого => предыдущее число и есть ваше; в примере на первой итерации получим 1-ку, т.к. `2*7 = 14 > 13` нам не подходит
  - вычитаем из нашего числа (в примере 13) то, что при умножении вышло `1*7`: получим 6 и снова в начало итерации к 6 прибавляем новую цифру

```
  132 |7
       ___
       18
   7
-=06
   62
   56
-= 06
```

- тут нацело не делится остаток 6.

Я подал идею, даже блок схему не написал по нормальному, - но, скорее всего, она не так тяжело реализуется, хотя нужна внимательность. :) Успехов.

Сори, я пытался как-то форматно написать, а не выходит почему-то.

Answer (score 2):

Сам алгоритм в виде блок-схем можете подсмотреть вот тут:

- [Divide routines](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/DOC1973.PDF)
- [AVR200: Multiply and divide routines](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc0936.pdf)

По сути - это бинарное деление в столбик.

Готовые функции (первые, какие попались, не знаю, насколько хороши):

- [Integer division](http://www.bearcave.com/software/divide.htm)
- [Division of two numbers without using division operator](http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/01/division-without-division-operator_24.html)

Answer (score 1):

алгоритмы деления в аппаратуре хорошо описаны в книге "Организация ЭВМ" Орлова, как для целых чисел, так и для вещественных.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void div(int a,int b)
{
    int quot=0,rem=0;
    for(int i = a-b;i>=0;i-=b)
       {
       quot++;
       rem=i;
       }
  printf("quot = %d rem = %d",quot,rem);
}
int main()
{
    div(29,5);
}
```

Comment: для плавающей запятой алгоритм если нужно скажи, но советую в ассемблер его сделать. Есть два простых типа алгоритмов для static point  и другой алгоритм по тяжылее для floating point.