# Функция деления на С++

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Задача: Реализовать функцию деления целых числе на языке С или С++.
В результате у меня получился код:

```
int div(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 0;
    int nextRes = 0;
    for (int  i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j)
        {
            result  += i;
            nextRes += i+1;
        }
        if (result <= a && nextRes > a)
        {   
            result = i;
            break;  
        }
        else
        {
            result = 0;
            nextRes = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Код вроде работает, но очень долго! Если кто сталкивался, подскажите более простой и быстрый алгоритм деления целых числе или улучшите этот.

Comment: В задаче есть какие-то дополнительные ограничения? Судя по коду, указано, что нельзя использовать встроенную операцию "/"?

Comment: Задача в том, чтобы реализовать операцию "/". Я делал через сложение, можно делать через вычитание. Через вычитание у меня получилась примерно та же скорость.

Answer (score 5):

Этот алгоритм отличается тем, что количество проходов фиксировано для любых чисел. Он несколько тяжеловесен для восприятия, но тут уж никуда не денешься. RANG выставлен в 16 просто так. Можно задать любой другой, который позволяет разрядная сетка используемого языка. Самое интересное в том, что на ассемблере, для уже забытых PDP-11 (СМ-4, ДВК), этот алгоритм умещался в 7 строк (машинных команд).

```
// #define RANG        16      // работаем с числами меньшими 2 в степени 16

// #define RANG_MASK   0x10000 // представляем RANG в виде числа

    // исходные данные
    /*
    long dividend;   // делимое 
    long divisor;    // делитель
    */

    // будущий результат
    long result    = 0; // результат
    long remainder = 0; // остаток

    // проверяем, не выходят ли начальные параметры за разрядную сетку
    if ((dividend >= RANG_MASK) || (divisor >= RANG_MASK))
    {
        // ERROR - ну здесь обработка ошибки: "введены неверные данные"
    }
    // манипуляции со знаком
    bool negativ = false;
    if (dividend < 0)
    {
        negativ  = !negativ;
        dividend = -dividend;
    }
    if (divisor < 0)
    {
        negativ = !negativ;
        divisor = -divisor;
    }
    // собственно вычисление
    for (int n = 0; n < RANG; n++)
    {
        result    = result    << 1;
        remainder = remainder << 1;
        dividend  = dividend  << 1;
        if (dividend & RANG_MASK)
        {
            ++remainder;
            dividend &= ~RANG_MASK;
        }
        if (remainder >= divisor)
        {
            remainder -= divisor;
            ++result;
        }
    }
    // коррекция знака
    if (negativ)
        result = -result;
/*
    получаем:
    result - результат
    remainder - остаток
*/
```

Comment: Я помню ДВК! :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
// так обозначим бесконечность
const int Infinity = 0x7FFFFFFF;

// функция деления неотрицательных чисел
unsigned div_positive( unsigned a, unsigned b )
{
    if( b == 0 ) return Infinity;
    unsigned remain = a;
    unsigned result = 0;
    while( remain >= b ) {
        remain -= b;
        result += 1;
    }
    return result;
}

// функция деления любых целых чисел
int div( int a, int b )
{
    if( b == 0 ) return Infinity;
    int positiveResult = div_positive( abs( a ), abs( b ) );
    if( ( a < 0 )&&( b < 0 ) ) return positiveResult;
    else if( ( a > 0 )&&( b > 0 ) ) return  positiveResult;
    else return ( - positiveResult);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Эта задача решается стандартным школьным [делением в столбик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#603), там довольно быстро: число итераций мало, используются + - *.